# Facebook like button gets broken on android after click

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, facebook-like

I have a website with a facebook like widget, and on android+chrome, after I click on the like button the button becomes gray (broken).

If I disable the following css rule the button looks ok again.

```
.pluginButtonPressed, .pluginButtonPressed:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #3e58a3;
}
```

Is this a known issue? I didn't find anything about it on facebook support.

Is there a way to fix it?

example img: http://i.imgur.com/HqyPBRA.png

Thanks.

Comment: What is your goal here?

Comment: what do you mean? I want the widget to display as it should.

Comment: Because I'm assuming that you added that CSS on your stylesheet for some reason... why don't you remove it as you said so

Comment: The widget is running in a iframe and my site css does not effect it. the above css is coming from facebook and exists in the iframe.